# Is this a typo? private _MyEntities => new MyEntities();

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm fixing a bug in some inherited code. There's a class which has a module-scoped variable which is an Entity Framework DataContext.

The problem is that data is not being saved to the database. When I change this...

```
private _MyEntities => new MyEntities();
```

to this...

```
private _MyEntities = new MyEntities();
```

... it all works fine. But I'm concerned that the developer may have used '=>' deliberately for some reason that I'm missing.

Is it a typo or was it supposed to be doing something that I don't understand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: neither of those are valid statements, you don't specify a type for either of them.

Comment: To help understand if its a typo, go look at where `_MyEntities` is used.  Is it used like a delegate, or like a simple object?

Comment: Note that the previous version would return a new instance every time it's called, the new version will return the same instance every time. Big difference

Answer (score 4):

First of all, neither line will compile as is. The two lines need to be:

```
private MyEntities _MyEntities => new MyEntities();
```

and

```
private MyEntities _MyEntities = new MyEntities();
```

The first example is using C# 6 syntax for a readonly property using an expression body. It is shorthand for doing the following in C# 5 and before:

```
private MyEntities _MyEntities { get { return new MyEntities(); } }
```

It has three differences from `private MyEntities _MyEntities = new MyEntities()`:

1. It is readonly. Your change allows the field to be changed. This could be addressed with `private readonly MyEntities _MyEntities = new MyEntities()` though.
2. The property is using lazy-loading. It's only initialized when the property is used. You new version, using a field, is initialized when the object is created. This may be a very important change; or it may have no effect, depending on what happens when you invoke the `MyEntities` constructor.
3. Every call to the property will create a new instance of `MyEntities`. Your field alternative will always return the same `MyEntities` instance. This may have been deliberate on the part of the person who wrote it, or it may be a potential bug.

Comment: The expression-bodied property won't have a backing field generated, it's equivalent to `private MyEntities _MyEntities { get { return new MyEntities(); } }`.  A C# 6 read-only property would look like `private MyEntities _MyEntities { get; } = new MyEntities();`  The distinction is important (if `MyEntities` is a reference type) because accessing the expression-bodied property will create a new instance of `MyEntities` every time whereas the read-only property would return the same instance every time.

Comment: @Kyle, very good point. I've corrected my answer to address that.